# Generating a random sparse matrix using a custom discrete distribution in SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I would like to generate a sparse matrix using a custom discrete distribution.

E.g.:

```
from scipy.sparse import random
from scipy import stats

xk = np.arange(7)
pk = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
custm = stats.rv_discrete(name='custm', values=(xk, pk))
rvs = custm.rvs

dens = 0.5

S = random(1, 8, density=dens, data_rvs=rvs)
print(S.A)
```

I would expect to get something like so:

```
[4, 5, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

The above code works just fine for rvs of a continuous distribution (such as rvs = stats.norm().rvs), but when I use a discrete distribution I am met with this error:

```
  File "Python\Python310\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_construct.py", line 875, in random
    vals = data_rvs(k).astype(dtype, copy=False)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

This error persists even if convert the xk array to floats using np.array(xk,dtype=np.float64).

I have considered some work-arounds such as generating array indices in advance and then randomly picking xk values. A bit messy, but do-able. But I suspect I am not understanding about how sparse.random handles random variates?

Comment: Showing the full error message might help.  I expect it occurs in `sparse.random`, but I don't know what it would be doing at this point.  Keep in mind that is has to generate 3 sets of random values - the row and column indices, as well as the values.  I've never used `data_rvs`, so can't say from experience what it accepts.

Comment: Look at the `random` code, I see it uses `vals = data_rvs(k).astype(dtype, copy=False)`, where `k` is the number of nonzero values it needs (based on density).  So `data_rvs(k)` should return a numpy array of length `k`.  The `astype` converts it to float (if needed).

Comment: Your `custm.rvs(10)` returns the number `13`.  It should return an array of 10 values.  `stats.norm().rvs(10)` does this.

Comment: Sorry -- updated with the full error message.  `stats.norm().rvs` works just fine as an argument; it seems that it produced an np array whereas the rvs of the discrete dist'n produces an int for some reason?

Comment: So your problem isn't with `sparse`, but with `stats` - I'll let you study its docs.

Answer (score 3):

The docs on rv_discrete.rvs() say this:

> size
>
> Defining number of random variates (Default is 1). Note that size has to be given as keyword, not as positional argument.

[Source.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.rvs.html#scipy.stats.rv_discrete.rvs)

However, scipy.sparse.random() passes the size as a positional argument:

```
vals = data_rvs(k).astype(dtype, copy=False)
```

Therefore, the fix is to define a lambda function which accepts a positional argument and calls rvs() with a keyword argument.

```
S = random(1, 8, density=dens, data_rvs=lambda k: rvs(size=k))
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to define `custm` like this:

```
custm = stats.rv_discrete(name='custm', values=(xk, pk))()
```

Note the addition of `()` at the end of that line.  This causes `custm` to be an instance of `rv_discrete_frozen`.  The first argument of the `rvs()` method of this instance is `size`, which is what you want.